# How to put cross check image instead of right check in CheckBox Selection in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, css, checkbox

I am using ASP:Checkbox. When I check the checkbox I want a cross sign instead of the usual right check sign in the checkbox.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I can do this?

Thanks,
Vaibhav.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this natively in ASP.net as ultimately the check boxes are handled by the browser. You can use css and javascript to achieve this. The following 2 article should get you down the right path:

http://webhole.net/2010/02/06/how-to-style-checkboxes/

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Basically you are hiding the "normal" check boxes and replacing them with images.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for quick reply. I seen link references you given but I want to do that for ASP:Checkbox and link gives example for HTML checkbox . And I have server side code for that checkbox selection so any other idea for this.

Comment: @VaibhavDeshmukh the ASP:Checkbox will end up being rendered in the browser as an HTML check box so you need to handle the transformation browser side. Have a look at the HTML code rendered in the browser by viewing source from the browser. Or better still use Firebug for fire fox to inspect elements once rendered to the browser